# Oxite Blog Engine: Required Dlls missing

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2, blogs, oxite

i have just downloaded [Oxite blogging](http://oxite.codeplex.com/) engine. some dll's are missing in the downloaded package namely Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.dll and others with Microsoft.Practices prefix. where can i find these assemblies?

Answer (score 1):

you need to install Dependencies for Oxite Blog engine

- *Install Unity Application Block 1.2
  Oxite uses Unity Application Block as our dependency injection container. Download and run the setup program (MSI) from Microsoft downloads at http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=2C8B79E7-AE56-4F90-822E-A1E43C49D12E&displaylang=en.*

Answer (score 0):

check your pc

They can be located in the :
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Enterprise Library 4.0 - May 2008\Bin\Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.dll

or 
microsoft provide guide:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff650106.aspx